# How can I export dataframes to each Excel sheet?

Tags: python, pandas

I used for loop to make a dataframe and I want to export these data frames for each Excel sheet, and has each sheet name.

For example, first, save the created dataframe with the name "a" in the first Excel worksheet, and the next dataframe with the name "b" in the second Excel worksheet.
these dataframes are made by for loop.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

**Code**:

```
dfs=[]
for loop:    
    dfs.append(dfx)

    names = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
    for name, df in zip(names, dfs):
       df.to_csv(f'~/Desktop/df{name}.tsv', index=False, header=False, sep='\t')
```

**Code Explanation**:
`dfs` is array to keep data frames which are created inside outer loop, names is for keeping alphabetic or unique names. `zip()` function creates an iterator that will aggregate elements from two or more iterables, so name and `df` iterate through.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `pandas.DataFrame.to_excel` method available

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html